# Refresh django sitemap

Tags: python, django, sitemap

I recently switched my urls for a django app from displaying ids to displaying slugs as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
]
```

However I notice that in my sitemap, the urls are still displaying with the ids. How can I update the sitemap to show the new urls? I tried deleting and adding them back but nothing changed. My sitemap is defined as below:

```
class PostSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "monthly"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the following function to the sitemap class

```
    def location(self, item):
         return reverse('blog:detail', args=[str(item.slug)])
```